# Regular expression Java, return the whole row?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to get the whole row as my output. For example when i type kp1
I want the whole row CVBN.... returned.

```
begin abc
CVBN(r,t,t) + PPP(l,r) <-> ZEK(r!1).R(l!1,r) kp1,km1
TNBC(l,r) + SSR(r,t,t) <-> KPT(l,r!1).XXXX(l,r!1) kp2,km2
TLCX(l!+,(r,t,t)) + VV(l!+,r) <-> BB(l!+,r!1).R(l!+,r!1) kp3,km3
end abc
```

I tried the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("kp1");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mytextFromAbove);

// Find all matches
while (matcher.find()) 
{
    // Get the matching string
    match = matcher.group();
}
```

This only returns the substring **kp1**.
Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It surprises me that it returns anything at all. Unless the interface has changed significantly, it looks as if you're using your long text _as the regular expression_ and searching for something it describes in the string `"kp1"`.

Comment: thanks..i corrected that...but still it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your expression to `^.*kp1.*$`

Comment: You also should enable `MULTILINE` for your pattern: `... Pattern.compile("^.*kp1.*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);`

Comment: Why does he need multiline if he's matching one line?

Comment: @MK: if you don't specify multiline those anchors match start and end of input, not a line.